# How to Join tables in MySql workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

How do I Join tables with mySql workbench visually? without using any SQL script or typing it into the query menu? I am new when it comes to using this MySql workbench, but I tried looking at their documentation and I haven't found any, any help??

Comment: It's been awhile since you asked this quesiton, any tips on what you've found since then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these links:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/visual-database-creation-with-mysql-workbench/

http://www.packtpub.com/article/visual-mysql-database-design-in-mysql-workbench

They give some good screenshot-oriented tutorials (especially since this is for using the graphical user interface to create your database and its objects)

Comment: This does not answer the question I have (and I think is being asked above), which is how to generate the SQL for a JOIN query using workbench's GUI. Is there any way to do so? (After having created the tables and their relationships.) Like is possible in Ms SQL's visual tools  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191279.aspx

Comment: those links do not explain how to create JOIN query with MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

To join tables without using any SQL script or typing it into the query menu:

1) Use the EER diagram:  on the menu bar ==> FILE ==> select NEW MODEL from the dropdown, then ==> click on the "Model" tab use dropdown to "Add Diagram", that will open the grid screen where you can simply click on the GUI's on the left side of the grid to create tables, join tables... you'll need to save your model for future use, if needed.